# Webview not responding to touch events

Tags: java, android, webview, touch

Im using an embedded webview to display a webpage which is made up of image thumbnails. These thumbnails are links to further webpages. Now my application randomly stops responding to my touch events on these thumbnails. It happens more frequently when the device wakes up from a standby. but this problem is fixed when i load some other page and come back to the thumbnails page.

I tried adding an `onClickListener` to the webview but it never return anything, even when the application is running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Android `Webview` component has a bug due to which it randomly stops responding to touch events. 
For more details http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=929

Bug is due to the attribute `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the web view component. Workaround can be any other value for this attribute instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: I am using match_parent attribute and I am seeing the same issue.