# How to Fetch Serial Number from Android Mobile Browser using Java Scripting which will be from web application source running in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, jsp, web-applications, mobile-browser

I can able to find UniqueId,Serial,IMEI,OS and IP Address from Android Mobile
Native Application.

But, I could not able to find the above device information via mobile browser app, 
which will be from web application source running in mobile browser.

Note: I reffered many links, regarding this, they sugggest only able to fetch 
the device os type using UserAgent from mobile browser.

please Anyone help me to get out of this.

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 6):

Due to security concerns IMEI, Serial number information is not exposed to Javascript running on the browser of mobile application. You can get OS, IP details from the request headers.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) one can access native device functionality over javascript. With [Cordova device plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) you can have most of the information, however to get IMEI one need to write a custom plugin or you can find plenty of examples on google.

If your requirement is to just uniquely identify your clients on all platform, getting unique ID will do the job and using Cordova you can call it from your own javascript.

Comment: HI Himanshu, Cordova plug used to convert the native app. but, It could not use this plugin to web application mobile browser..

Comment: can you cross check your second point again.using javascript is correct. but, here we could not get those details from Native App. here just run our website in to mobile browser( android firefox,chrome browser), that time need the device unique id details like IMEI, SERIAL,OS, etc

Comment: Hi harikrishnan, sorry I did not read the question properly. From browser accessing device information is not possible so far. However if you can explain for what purpose you need that we can think of alternate possibilities.