# How to check if device has a given capability?

Tags: java, javascript, android, capability

I am building a webapp, and experimenting with figuring out which capabilities the android device has.

Is there a "capability" or "feature" registry I can look this up in? Take an example: Let's say I need to know whether a device has phone capabilities or perhaps a camera capability. Is there a centralized key store where I can check for these constants?

What I'm trying to create is something to the tune of this:

```
public String HasCapability(String key) {
    return some.mystical.namespace.Capabilities.ContainsKey(key);
}
```

I'm kind of new to this (I'm a C# guy), so excuse my syntax.

Comment: Use answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767638/calling-android-native-apis-from-javascript-functions-of-embedded-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
}
```

For more details

[Check if device has a camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944117/check-if-device-has-a-camera)

Comment: thanks this worked a treat. However, if I get the string "FEATURE_CAMERA" from a different source, how can I make this work the same way?