# Can you detect with jQuery (or anything, but C++) if the volume button is pressed?

Tags: android, jquery, ios

I doubt it is, but is it possible to detect if the volume button is pressed, by jQuery or any of the web languages?

I want to do some basic user testing, to investigate by which way it's best to call a certain function; either a gesture or a hardware button. I't not a problem to call a function based on a touch gesture, but calling a function based on pressing a hardware button is a bit more difficult.

As I got both an Android phone and iPhone here, it doesn't matter if it only works on one of both devices.

*Since I can't write C++, this language isn't an option. Even though this language does support hardware button detection*

**What I want to create**
It's the most basic version of a test: I want to see by which way people would like to switch from round to squared display.

There is a simple round object in the center and it should transform to a square, based on any of the following gestures: A hardware button press (volume), pinch, pinch-out, 4-finger pinch out, 2 finger swipe down.

Comment: You really should at least mention somewhere in the question which cross platform framework you are using.

Comment: I'm not using any. One sec, I'll add what I want to achieve

Comment: Then how is `jQuery` related to all this?

Comment: As jQuery is probably the most easy way to achieve anything non-native.

Comment: How do you expect to run your script on the device? You need some kind of framework for that. Otherwise how do you hope to access anything related to the hardware of the device?

Comment: I haven't got a clue, that's what I'm hoping to find out- and that's why I posted this question. At least that part should've been clear enough..?

Comment: It's not clear at all. Before you ask how to do something you should at least be sure which technologies you want to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78341/discussion-between-sander-schaeffer-and-xaver-kapeller).

Comment: Seriously.. I said I don't care which technology, language I want to use, as long it's not C++ or Java, since those are native languages and I don't want to use xCode. I just want to find a way to actually detect if a hardware button is pressed. If someone could tell me which languages could assist me with that, I'm fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
If you're running this in a mobile browser (e.g. Safari or Chrome), you don't have access to the volume buttons.

**Explanation:**
JQuery relies on JavaScript which relies on a browser, webview (for native apps), or a node.js server (irrelevant for you). Webviews tend to be like a browser but with fewer features. The main browsers out there do not provide access to the volume buttons. Therefore, jQuery isn't going to solve this for you.

**Solution:**
You're going to need a native app if you really want to use the volume buttons. On Android, apps are written in Kotlin (based on Java). On iOS, they're written in Swift (or Objective-C). If you know only one or none of those languages, there are cross-platform tools that'll let you write the app once and deploy to both platforms. Depending on the level of control you want, you could use a tool that provides a unified framework or go for a fancy drag-and-drop builder. There are TONS of options out there.

**Extra:**
Looking at your history, it seems like you're a "web" guy. If you just want to use jQuery/JavaScript for the convenience, you could create a simple native app that basically does just two things: 1) Load your webapp, and 2) Provide an API to the webapp for accessing the volume buttons. This topic will get you moving in that direction: [Calling android native APIs from javascript functions of embedded WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767638/calling-android-native-apis-from-javascript-functions-of-embedded-webview)

I encourage other web folks to hack around a little on mobile platforms. You never know when a base level understanding could come in handy.